# Calculating difference in two values in the same column

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

I want to find the difference (the Profit & Loss) when I combine records with the same `CATEGORY` value (e.g. A's will be combined and C's will be combined).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select category,
       sum(iif(side = "BUY", - quantity * price, quantity * price)) as net
from t
where side in ("BUY", "SELL")  -- may not be necessary
group by category;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select category, buy.amt-sell.amt ProfitorLoss
from
(SELECT sum(price*quantity) amt, Category
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE side = 'BUY'
GROUP BY Category) buy,
(SELECT sum(price*quantity) amt, Category
  FROM yourtable
 WHERE side = 'SELL'
GROUP BY Category) sell
where buy.category = sell.category
```

Comment: Access is giving me a missing operator error for the line "buy.amt-sell.amt ProfitorLoss".

Comment: Ry it in parenthesis (buy.amt-sell.amt) as Profitorloss